# How can I graph 2 normal distributions over one-another in the same plot?

Tags: r, rstudio, normal-distribution

One curve must use data that only has a 0, i.e. Male, value for the Gender variable. The other curve must use data that has a 1, i.e. Female, value for the Gender variable.

I'm using 2 variables: Opinion (for the distribution) and Gender (to create two curves).

Hopefully that is enough info for someone to help...

Comment: What have you tried so far, & what does your desired output look like?

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't indicate information about the type of graph nor an example data frame, here you have some suggestions.

```
# This installs and loads pacman, to use the p_loas function
if (!require('pacman')) install.packages('pacman'); library('pacman')

# sample data
value <- rnorm(n=100, mean=50, sd=5)
gen <- rep(x = c(1,2), 50)

df <- data.frame(value = as.numeric(value), gender = as.factor(gen))

# Option 1
p_load(ggjoy)
ggplot(df, aes(x = value, y = gender)) +
  geom_joy(scale = 2, alpha = .7, color = "black") +
  scale_fill_hue(l=30)
```

[image]

```
# Option 2
p_load(ggpubr)
ggdensity(df, x = "value",
          add = "mean", rug = TRUE,
          color = "gender", palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"), fill = "gender")
```

[image]

```
# Option 3
p_load(yarrr)
pirateplot(value ~ gender, df)
```

[image]